# Unable to restart after Ubuntu update

Tags: pi-4, power

I have Raspberry PI 4B 8 GB with "Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1034-raspi aarch64)"
I start Ubuntu and see message "System information disabled due to load higher than 4.0". I installed Ubuntu server and connected to PI with SSH. Then I update Ubuntu and disconnect SSH session. When I connect again PI shows temperature 44.5 C and I reboot PI. Then I am unable to connect to PI using SSH. I use USB-C tester to monitor current and voltage. It says stable voltage ~5.19 V and current is varied from 0.45 to 7.26 A (Strange my power supply 5V 3A). Current after reboot 0.19 A.

Disconnecting PI cooling fan temporary solves the issue with temperature raise to 56.5 C.
How do I make stable work of PI ?

Comment: It is probably a faulty fan.